# axios() method does not work for POST Request

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to send a `post` request from `startQuiz.ejs` page by clicking on `Go button` but always get `get` request executed on the server. If I use `postman`  then there is no problem but from `front end` is failed to execute `post` request.

I want output as **post request** but I got **get request** every time on the browser on clicking `GO button`

Here are my files

**startQuiz.ejs**

```
<%- include('./partial/header.ejs'); %>


<form id='abcd'>
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous ">

    const form = document.querySelector('#abcd');

    form.addEventListener('submit', async(event) => {

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('Log here');
        try {
            await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/startQuiz',
                data: {
                    firstName: 'Fred',
                },
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    });
</script>



<%- include('./partial/footer.ejs'); %>
```

**startQuiz.js route**

```
const express = require('express');
const { auth } = require('../middleware/auth');
const router = express.Router();
const Tag = require('../schemas/Tags');

router.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('../views/startQuiz.ejs');
});

router.post('/', async function(request, response) {
    response.send('post request');
});


module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const home = require('./routes/home');
const register = require('./routes/register');
const login = require('./routes/login');
const logout = require('./routes/logout');
const me = require('./routes/me');
const createQuestion = require('./routes/createQuestion');
const takeQuiz = require('./routes/takeQuiz');
const startQuiz = require('./routes/startQuiz');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const { checkUser } = require('./middleware/auth');
const path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(cookieParser());



app.use('*', checkUser);
app.use('/', home);
app.use('/register', register);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/logout', logout);
app.use('/me', me);
app.use('/createQuestion', createQuestion);
app.use('/takeQuiz', takeQuiz);
app.use('/startQuiz', startQuiz);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8200;
app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Running on ${port}`) });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `axios.post()` method or using `post` lowercase instead of `POST` in the request options ?

Comment: Also I am pretty sure in you event listener `ex` will be defined always, since it'S the event parameter, so you callback will never executed the request !

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form will navigate to a new page and cancel the Ajax request.

If you want to make the Ajax request you need to prevent the default behaviour of the form submission.

```
ex.preventDefault();
```

(`ex` is a pretty unusual variable name to represent the Event object though, `e`, `evt` and `event` are more common).

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in the listener callback is probably the `Event`, you are naming it `ex` in your code, but you are checking if it's defined and if so return, the code after will never be executed. Maybe you are mistaking it by an error ?

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', async(ex) => {
  if (ex) {
   console.log(ex);
   return;
  }
        
  // code will be stopped here, since ex (Event) will be defined always
  // ...

});
```

try this instead

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', async(event) => {

  event.preventDefault();
  
  // perform request here   

});
```

Bit background info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: Tried your approach but not get required output

Comment: So your are saying that the express route POST for /startQuiz is never fired ? Or what's the problem now ?

Comment: yes but now console.log('Log here') also not work in form.addEventListener() and i also found fetch() in place of axios() also not worked

Comment: That's odd ... let me check if i can spin up an example to look at